# How to limit calculations of r.grow.distance to contiguous cells in raster mask?

Tags: raster, grass-gis, distance

I have a layer with rasterized vector polygons (white cells) in a GRASS database. The region is set to the bounding box of the polygons. I also set a raster mask to mask all cells between these polygons (grey cells). In addition, I have a second layer with rasterized linestrings which a located inside the polygons (coloured cells).

Now I want to use `r.grow.distance` to calculate the distance of every raster cell to the next raster feature BUT only inside the same contiguous "zone". For example, raster cells of polygon 1 should only be related to the rose raster feature. Also, polygon to would be assigned to the purple feature, although there is no raster feature on it. Currently, the south-eastern cells of polygon 1 would be associated with the purple raster feature, because it's closer than the rose on.

How can I force `r.grow.distance` to limit the calculation to each contiguous zone and not to "jump" across masked cells?

I would like to avoid running this command for every polygon separately as a possible work-around.

[image]